# how to Use the LIKE statement to find songs that contain "Verse" followed by a character or number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

This is my 'MySongs' Table in my 'Music' database:

```
create table MySongs (
    id int(15) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    artist varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    genre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    lyrics text NOT NULL,
    length int(20) NOT NULL,
    release_date int(20) NOT NULL
    );
```

I am running this code:

```
SELECT * FROM MySongs WHERE lyrics LIKE 'verse%';
```

but there are 0 rows returned even though there are songs with the word 'verse' in the lyrics column.

Comment: Your expression will only match lyrics which start with `verse`. Use `%verse%` to match verse anywhere in the column.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an an INT declaration is fairly meaningless, and in this instance, probably best omitted.